# Does Phusion Passenger automatically precompile assets after restarting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, passenger

Via `git`, I downloaded the latest version of my web-app to our server. I did a `touch tmp/restart.txt` but this didn't precompile my assets. I did a `rake assets:clobber assets:precompile` and this refreshed my assets.

**Is Passenger supposed to refresh my asset pipeline automatically? If it is, what are some things I ought to look into to troubleshoot this?**

Running rails 4.0.0 (unsure of how to check my passenger version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Passenger does not compile assets for you. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production - By default Rails in production does "assumes assets have been precompiled and will be served as static assets by your web server".

Do you have a deployment script such as Capistrano ? Most rails deployment scripts should trigger precompilation.

Comment: very old, but here is the documentation in passenger how to serve precompiled assets: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/dev/ruby/rails_integration.html